# SQL Where clause condition if variable is empty or not

Tags: sql

How can I write the **WHERE clause** of a SQL query that if a variable has a value it uses that value and if the variable is blank works as if it wasn't there.

Like this:

General query:

```
Select * from table1 where color = $colorFilter and size = $sizeFilter
```

If $colorFilter has a value: **$colorFilter = "blue"** then the query should execute like stated before. But if $colorFilter is blank: **$colorFilter = ""** I would like to not take into account that clause:

```
Select * from table1 where size = $sizeFilter
```

How can I write that in a generic way? It seems like a very straight-forward issue but cannot seem to get it. Thanks!

Comment: `where ($colorFilter = 'white' or $colorFilter is null) ...`

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question to make it a little more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Select * from table1 where ($colorFilter = "" or $colorFilter = 'white') and ($sizeFilter  = "" or $sizeFilter = 'medium')

Answer (score 0):

You can use IFNULL for MYSQL, if the value is null it will return the second parameter.

`Select * from table1 where color = IFNULL($colorFilter,color) and size = IFNULL($sizeFilter,size)`

Change IFNULL to ISNULL for MS access and SQL server, NVL for oracle

Comment: Brilliant. The key is that when $colorFilter is NULL the where clause is like "WHERE color = color", or "WHERE true and that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```css
   declare @ccmd nvarchar(max)
   declare @colorFilter nvarchar(max)
   declare @sizeFilter nvarchar(max)
   set @ccmd='Select * from table1 where ' 
   if ltrim(rtrim(@colorFilter))='blue' 
     set @ccmd = @ccmd + ' color ='+ @colorFilter +' AND size ='+ @sizeFilter +''
  if ltrim(rtrim(@colorFilter))='' 
     set @ccmd = @ccmd + ' size='+ @sizeFilter +''
   EXECUTE sp_executesql @ccmd
```

Comment: above example as MS Sql Server. please for sample code